Writing an expect script to execute commands on remote server that Linux itself might not be familiar with such as 'configure terminal'
So far I have spawned a bash script in my expect script that logins to the remote server automatically, which works. Now within my expect script I am trying to run commands such as 'configure terminal' and 'copy startup-config ftp configuration-id 1' on the remote server that i login to. These aren't commands that Linux is familiar with which makes it tricky. Any help will do thank you.

Once the expect script uses the spawn to login to the remote server how can I continue with the expect script to run the commands that I need to within the remote server.

Why would it matter whether Linux is familiar with them? Expect just sends input and reads output, it doesn't know what the commands do.

E.g. it's very common to write Expect scripts to control Cisco routers (which is what this sounds like).

Typically, you'll write something like:
spawn some process

expect "some pattern for login"
send "thePassword\r"

expect "some pattern that is the command-line prompt"
send "some command\r"
# repeat as necessary

expect "some pattern that is the command-line prompt"
send "exit\r"
expect elf

Often you need to capture the command output. Do this:
expect -re "(.*)\r\nsome pattern that is the command-line prompt"
set cmdOutput $expect_out(1,string)

Where:

expect uses CRLF to represent newlines in the output
The 1 there represents the first set of capturing parentheses from the regex pattern.
There must not be a space after the comma.

